# Direct sum of divisible abelian groups is divisible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to solve this in the following way:
1.Divisible abelian group is injective $\Bbb Z$-module
2.Direct product of injective modules is injective
(Here I need to show direct sum of injective modules is injective but I can't. As i know it is only true for Noetherian Rings.)\
3.An injective $\Bbb Z$-module is a divisible abelian group.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: In general direct sums of injectives need not be injective; but they are for modules over a Noetherian ring.

Comment: Please suggest me how can i proceed?

Comment: If your aim is to prove the assertion in the title, the simplest approach is to try to prove it directly.

Comment: Ok thank you i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the most direct way? Given divisible abelian groups $A_i$ how does an element $a$ in the sum $\bigoplus_i A_i$ look like? And if you know that $a_i/n$ exists for each $a_i \in A_i$ and $0\neq n\in \mathbb Z$, how does a choice for $a/n$ look like?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

An abelian group $A_i$ is divisible if for each $n$, the  homomorphism
$$A_i\xrightarrow{\enspace\times n\enspace}A_i\qquad\text{(in additive notation)}$$
is surjective.
Just prove a direct sum of surjections is a surjection.